# Регулярные выражения Java, выбор из строки

Tags: java

Можно из такой строки:
548673++++++1028    809216  /RU/CARD2CARD ALFA_MOBILE>MOSCOW          31.05.17 31.05.17 1500.00       RUR MCC6536
 выбрать с помощью регулярных выражений только ALFA_MOBILE>MOSCOW? Каким образом? Кучу комбинаций попробовал, не получилось.

Comment: не совсем понятно, по каким параметрам выбирать. если у вас постоянно такой формат во всех записях, то можно просто поделить сплитом по пробелам и всех делов. как-то так string.split(" ")[3];

Comment: Что означает "выбрать"? Получить из длинной строки заданную строку? Так она у вас уже есть в качестве образца. Или проверить содержится ли образец в длинной строке? Нужно уточнить, что именно вы хотите...

Answer (score 3):

если взять CARD2CARD за якорь, то вот это работает

```
(?<=CARD2CARD)\s([^\s]+)
```

Если брать за основу формат сообщения и привязаться к пробелу как разделителю, то можно вот так

```
[\d+]{16}\s\d+\s[\/\w]+\s([^\s]+)
```